# Plotting linear hyperplane using primal vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

Using svmtrain and svmmodel, we're supposed to plot a hyperplane to separate two collections of data. Through the sample, I have the data:

```
c = [1 1; 2 1.5; 2 1;3 1.5];
N = 10; X = []; sigma = 0.2;

for i = 1:4
    X = [X; sigma*randn(N,2) + repmat(c(i,:),N,1)];
end
Y = [ones(1,2*N) -ones(1,2*N)];

plot(X(1:end/2,1),X(1:end/2,2),'+')
hold all
plot(X(end/2+1:end,1),X(end/2+1:end,2),'o')
hold on
```

[image: ScatterPlot_SampleData]

So, from my understanding, I have to use the primal vector to obtain the hyperplane as: y = w'x + b, which is the following:

```
model = svmtrain(Y',X,'-s 0 -t 0 -c 1')

w = model.SVs' * model.sv_coef;
b = -model.rho;

if model.Label(1) == -1
    w = -w;
    b = -b;
end
```

However, when I add

```
plot(w+b)
```

I get:

[image: ScatterPlot_Separated_Hyperplane]

Which is not the desired hyperplane. I've played with the values as much as I can and looked up different samples of this kind, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to use the primal and bias to produce the proper hyperplane.